# How can I avoid modifying IMyClass and MyClass when I want to add a new method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

We use Mock objects that rely on dependency injection, interfaces, etc in order to unit test our web service.  It always seems like the process of making modifications could be streamlined a bit, if (for example) an interface could be generated from a concrete class. If I add a new public property `DeleteUser` to `MyClass`, it's clear that it should also go into `IMyClass`.

Is there such a way to streamline this process? Or is our method of testing itself outdated perhaps?

Comment: VS2015 provides this functionality. select enough code to make the intellisense realize that the selected code is part of a class. Select refactor -> Extract interface method.

Comment: I believe some people won't agree with me, but to me it's a good practice to always begin with adding your method signature in your interface first

Comment: @bashrc This is a good feature, but I'm looking for something that removes the requirement for the dev to change anything at all before checkin.

yanyankelevich I think typically they are added together; the point of my question is that if you find yourself doing the same thing over and over, you can't help but ask yourself if it can be automated in some way.

Comment: You either add it to the interface or not - if you don't add it to the interface then you can't unit test against the interface - you'd have to unit test against the concrete class.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That is the *reason* I'm asking the question, but not the question. Imagine for example if as part of your build process, `IMyClass` was generated for you from the public members of `MyClass`, or if c# had a language feature like `interfacefrom(MyClass)`. You could write all your code with this (somewhat awkward) helper, and then when you added a method or property to `MyClass`, the interface would just know.

Comment: Automatically adding new members to an interface based on a change to a derived class sounds like madness to me. What happens if the class implements multiple interfaces - which interface would have the new element added to it? Also, what would happen to other classes that implemented the same interface? What if those other classes were in different assemblies? This is not a route to go down. The best thing to do is to use the built-in refactoring support to add new methods to an interface explicitly.

Comment: @Rollie As I understand that anyone can want to avoid doing thing over and over, what you want to achieve goes against the very principle of an interface. I don't say its impossible at all, it's just a bad idea.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you make some fair points - specific implementation, imagine the hypothetical `interfaceof(MyClass)`. Adding a property would not need to change any tangible class - it would affect the generation of one. A method being added to `MyClass` would impact the interface generated by `interfaceof`, but it wouldn't 'add' the new method to any existing interface. This makes the multiple interface concern a non-issue I believe. Other classes wouldn't directly implement as `class AnotherClass : interfaceof(Myclass)` unless they were specifically trying to mock.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by @yanyankelevich the new method/property is added to the interface first. Next, you open a class implementing the original interface, and VS (or is it actually ReSharper?) will offer to implement the missing members, i.e. it adds the property / function with a `throw new NotImplementedException()` in the body. Now replace that with your code. That's it.

Comment: Visual Studio has this functionality even without ReSharper.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, when using [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) you can mock concrete classes with no need of creating an interface before doing so.